DataGridComboBoxColumn - как привязать команду к смене значения?
Есть DataGrid, в нём задан столбец DataGridComboBoxColumn. Как привязать команду к смене значения выбранного элемента в нём?
Пробовал через Interaction.Triggers, но он на DataGridComboBoxColumn похоже не работает.
Пробовал вот так вот через триггер :
<DataGridComboBoxColumn .. >
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.ChangeCategoryCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>

Но не срабатывает, хотя команда и путь к ней прописаны верно. С других событий на форме этот биндинг работает.
В качестве обходного решения сделал через обработчик событий в самом окне.
 <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
     <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
         <EventSetter Event="SelectionChanged" Handler="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>

private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    (DataContext as RegistryDeviceViewModel).ChangeCategoryCommand.Execute(sender);
}

Но это ведь плохой стиль в рамках паттерна MVVM? Как правильно закрепить команду за сменой выбора в DataGridComboBoxColumn ?

На каких-то контролах по-моему и команда какая-то готовая была для привязки на изменение SelectedItem, но могу путать, я не долго с WPF разбирался. Но лучше просто на биндинг данных завязать, да.

@CrazyElf нет никакого смысла в команде, когда есть сеттер. Эти костыли Interaction.Triggers вообще путают людей, и они вместо того чтобы учить как работает WPF, творят Winforms в XAML. У меня много проектов WPF разного размера и навороченности, но нигде не используется библиотека Interaction.Triggers, в первую очередь за ненадомностью, так как многие штуки без неё делаются сильно проще и XAML выглядит аккуратнее.

@aepot Interaction.Triggers это плохой стиль и лучше от них отвыкать? В приличных местах их не стоит использовать?

@Pavel его используют в основном те, кто плохо знает XAML/WPF. В нормальной ситуации я вообще не представляю, зачем они нужны. Если очень хочется что сил нет дёрнуть команду из обработчика событий, сделай это в код-бихайнде, вот прямо как у вас в вопросе. Но это может потребоваться примерно никогда.

Зачем команду совать туда, где есть привязанное свойство (данные)?
Документация
Берём комбобокс колонку, привязываем SelectedItemBinding
<DataGridComboBoxColumn SelectedItemBinding="{Binding ComboItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding ComboItems}" />

Во вьюмодели делаем свойство, и в сеттере прописываем вызов кода:
private T _comboItem;

public T ComboItem
{
    get => _comboItem;
    set
    {
        _comboItem = value;
        OnComboBoxValueChanged();
    }
}

private void OnComboBoxValueChanged()
{
    // вызовется при изменении значения
}


Я правильно понимаю, что если нужно отслеживать и реагировать изменения в объектах лежащих в DataGrid, то просто использую INotifyPropertyChanged, подписываю на него нужные методы и через них все делаю?

@Pavel верно...

Ясно. Спасибо вам большое. Почему-то сам в эту сторону даже и не начал думать. Упёрся во View и события на нём, хотя действительно через сами объекты всё гораздо проще и элегантнее.

@Pavel Ну это вообще основная парадигма WPF - всё делать через binding-и и нотификации об изменениях.
